# Elastic Search: how to see the indexed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, attr-protected

I had a problem with ElasticSearch and Rails, where some data was not indexed properly because  of attr_protected. Where does Elastic Search store the indexed data? It would be useful to check if the actual indexed data is wrong.

Checking the mapping with `Tire.index('models').mapping` does not help, the field is listed.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to explore your ElasticSearch cluster is to use [elasticsearch-head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head).

You can install it by doing:

```
cd elasticsearch/
./bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Then (assuming ElasticSearch is already running on your local machine), open a browser window to:

`http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/`

Alternatively, you can just use `curl` from the command line, eg:

Check the mapping for an index:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty=1'
```

Get some sample docs:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_search?pretty=1'
```

See the actual terms stored in a particular field (ie how that field has been analyzed):

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
 {
    "facets" : {
       "my_terms" : {
          "terms" : {
             "size" : 50,
             "field" : "foo"
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

More available here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide

## UPDATE : Sense plugin in [Marvel](https://github.com/bleskes/sense)

By far the easiest way of writing `curl`-style commands for Elasticsearch is the [Sense plugin in Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/download/).

It comes with source highlighting, pretty indenting and autocomplete.

Note: [Sense was originally a standalone chrome plugin but is now part of the Marvel project](https://github.com/bleskes/sense).

Comment: In the case like Robin's, I think it's enough to just inspect the data with curl `curl localhost:9200/my_index/_search?q=*&pretty` -- assuming there's a limited set of docs in the index.

Comment: Sense plugin for chrome is great for using the REST API. and _head is nice for checking purposes!

Comment: [Facets are now deprecated](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html)

Comment: Thanks this was really useful.  Btw the syntax is ./bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head .  i.e. you don't need the hyphen in front of the install.

Comment: elasticsearch-head chrome extension is also very handy

Answer (score 67):

Absolutely the easiest way to see your indexed data is to view it in your browser. **No downloads or installation needed.**

I'm going to assume your elasticsearch host is `http://127.0.0.1:9200`.

**Step 1**

Navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v` to list your indices. You'll see something like this:

[image]

**Step 2**

Try accessing the desired index:
`http://127.0.0.1:9200/products_development_20160517164519304`

The output will look something like this:

[image]

Notice the `aliases`, meaning we can as well access the index at:
`http://127.0.0.1:9200/products_development`

**Step 3**

Navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:9200/products_development/_search?pretty` to see your data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jan, it's just what I was looking for.

Comment: I just have a question, does `http://127.0.0.1:9200/products_development/_search?pretty=1` only shows sample data? it doesn't seem to show all the data

Comment: The docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/_the_search_api.html) state that search results default to first 10 documents (look for `hits.hits`)

Comment: This does not show the indexed data at all.  It only shows your source data—the very same thing you put in.  Doesn't answer OPs question.

Comment: ?pretty is enough, no need to add "=1"

Answer (score 11):

[ElasticSearch data browser](https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/elasticsearch-browser/wiki)

Search, charts, one-click setup....

Answer (score 5):

## Aggregation Solution

Solving the problem by grouping the data - DrTech's answer used facets in managing this but, [will be deprecated according to Elasticsearch 1.0 reference.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html)

```
Warning

Facets are deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You are encouraged to
migrate to aggregations instead.
```

Facets are replaced by aggregates - [Introduced in an accessible manner in the Elasticsearch Guide - which loads an example into sense.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations.html).

### Short Solution

The solution is the same except aggregations require `aggs` instead of `facets` and with a [count of 0 which sets limit to max integer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)  - [the example code requires the Marvel Plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/)

```
# Basic aggregation
GET /houses/occupier/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs" : {
        "indexed_occupier_names" : {    <= Whatever you want this to be
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "first_name",    <= Name of the field you want to aggregate
              "size" : 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Full Solution

Here is the Sense code to test it out - example of a houses index, with an occupier type, and a field first_name:

```
DELETE /houses

# Index example docs
POST /houses/occupier/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{ "first_name": "john" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "first_name": "john" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "first_name": "mark" }


# Basic aggregation
GET /houses/occupier/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs" : {
        "indexed_occupier_names" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "first_name",
              "size" : 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Response

Response showing the relevant aggregation code. With two keys in the index, John and Mark.

```
    ....
    "aggregations": {
      "indexed_occupier_names": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "john",     
               "doc_count": 2     <= 2 documents matching
            },                        
            {
               "key": "mark",
               "doc_count": 1     <= 1 document matching
            }
         ]
      }
   }
   ....
```

Answer (score 4):

A tool that helps me a lot to debug ElasticSearch is [ElasticHQ](http://elastichq.org). Basically, it is an HTML file with some JavaScript. No need to install anywhere, let alone in ES itself: just download it, unzip int and open the HTML file with a browser.

Not sure it is the best tool for ES heavy users. Yet, it is really practical to whoever is in a hurry to see the entries.

Answer (score 2):

Kibana is also a good solution. It is a data visualization platform for Elastic.If installed it runs by default on port 5601.

Out of the many things it provides. It has "Dev Tools" where we can do your debugging.

For example you can check your available indexes here using the command

```
GET /_cat/indices
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome then you can simply use this extension named as Sense it is also a tool if you use Marvel.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig

Answer (score 1):

Following @JanKlimo example, on terminal all you have to do is:

to see all the Index:

`$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v'`

to see content of Index `products_development_20160517164519304`:

`$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/products_development_20160517164519304/_search?pretty=1'`