# How can I retrieve the contents of an Azure Search index?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

**The problem:**

I have created a search index for a blob store of HTML documents on Azure. I'm using Azure search to query the documents from this index.

What I would like to retrieve is the contents of the search index itself. That is I want to retrieve the entire inverted index.

**What I have tried:**

I have inspected the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/index-operations) and understand that I can retrieve the index definition with the [Get Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-index) operation, get individual documents, and see a sample token with the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer), but do not see a way to retrieve the actual inverted search index.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) and [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lookup-document) APIs are the way to retrieve documents from your Azure Search index. If you meant being able to see the content of the [inverted index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#stage-3-document-retrieval), the closest thing is the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) that allows you to inspect what searchable terms are extracted for any input string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really see how the Analyze API allows me to get any kind of content from the index. By the content i don't mean retrieving the documents themselves, but what is put into index for a given/all documents. Could you elaborate please. As far I understand Analyze API simply shows how the query is being broken down. Perhaps you meant feeding in a document into the API and see what kind of tokens then are used for indexing. While that's reasonable to a certain extent, that does not really answer my question.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what this API would do so I can understand better?

Comment: Perhaps pointing to a relevant elasticsearch questions could give a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. [Elastic Search: how to see the indexed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954785/elastic-search-how-to-see-the-indexed-data) Thanks.

Comment: Which of the provided answers are your referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search does not currently offer a way to retrieve the actual search index. If you are trying to do something like [retrieve term frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462318/does-azure-search-store-term-frequencies-for-searchable-fields/55463739) you will have to implement that yourself using other Azure features like the Analyze API.

You can [cast your vote here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/37258444-allow-access-to-stored-term-frequencies-for-search) to show support for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

To see the individual documents, you can use the [Azure Search REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/) for Search and Lookup or you can use the Search Explorer that is accessible from the Azure Search resource.

[image: Search Explorer]

If you are looking at understanding how Azure Search tokenizes the documents, use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to send sample text and see how your content is being tokenized.

[image]