# Does Azure Search store term frequencies for searchable fields?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

**The problem**

I understand that an Azure Search index for a searchable field creates an inverted index for each analyzed term, but cannot find within the documentation whether or not the term frequency for each term is stored.

**The Question**

Does Azure Search store the term frequencies for searchable fields somewhere? It seems as if it would be inefficient to calculate it for every search query when it would only need be computed once.

If so, is it possible to extract/download the term frequencies for the entire data set for separate processing steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do maintain term frequencies to compute things like TF/IDF quickly. Unfortunately there's no way currently to get that from Azure Search though.

Comment: It's dissapointing that Azure Search does not provide this feature, especially as similar products like ElasticSearch do. I've created a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/37258444-allow-access-to-stored-term-frequencies-for-search) on the Azure Search forums.